# JBoss remote deploy using ANT script

Tags: ant, jboss

Is it possible to do remote deploy of application (jar file) on JBoss using ANT script?

I found only few suggestions to do copy, but that can be done only on local server.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly there are two approaches to do remote JBOSS deploy.

- [Cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/JBoss+Remote+Deployer)
  This tool providing the ant scripts to do the remote deploy/control JBOSS instance
- Copy approach. The main steps are copy the application files to the jboss deploy folder and then start the jboss by remote command.
  For example, you can use [`SCP`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html) task to copy the application file to remote host, and then use the [`SSHEXEC`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html) task to remove control the JBOSS_BIN/ shell to start/stop jboss instance.

Answer (score 1):

To deploy remote you can use the jboss-cli, which is included in jboss. To make this approach work you have to have a local jboss install, because it includes the jboss-cli jar. Then you will need a jboss-user on the remote host, which you can create with the add-user.(sh|bat) on the remote box. Then you can use the following ant-tasks to deploy:

```
<!-- local installation to find the correct jar -->
<property name="local.jboss.home" value="/path/to/jboss/install/dir" />

<!-- remote parts -->
<property name="remote.jboss.host" value="some.ip" />
<property name="remote.jboss.port" value="9999" />

<property name="remote.jboss.user" value="user" />
<property name="remote.jboss.password" value="password" />


<!-- supposedly this is built by a seperate task -->
<property name="my.deployment" value="${basedir}/build/foo.war" />

<!-- preset to run jboss-cli, this can be used to push any command to a running
     jboss instance -->
<presetdef name="jboss-cli">
    <java jar="${jboss.home}/jboss-modules.jar" fork="true">
        <arg line="-mp ${jboss.home}/modules org.jboss.as.cli" />
        <arg value="--controller=${jboss.host}:${jboss.port}" />
        <arg value="--user=${jboss.user}" />
        <arg value="--password=${jboss.password}" />
        <arg value="--connect" />
    </java>
</presetdef>

<!-- the exec some command on cli command -->
<target name="exec-jboss">
    <jboss-cli failonerror="true">
        <arg value="${jboss.command}" />
    </jboss-cli>
</target>

<target name="deploy" description="deploys to a running jboss instance">
    <antcall target="exec-jboss">
        <param name="jboss.home" value="${local.jboss.home}" />
        <param name="jboss.host" value="${remote.jboss.host}" />
        <param name="jboss.port" value="${remote.jboss.port}" />
        <param name="jboss.command" value="deploy ${my.deployment}" />
    </antcall>
</target>
```